# Cygwin1.dll 'not found' when running a program written in C. How can I make Windows find it?

Tags: c, eclipse

So I'm trying to run my first hello world prog written in C. I compiled it in eclipse and get no errors, but when I try to run it I get:

"This application has failed to start because cygwin1.dll was not found."

I found [this post](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg08271.html) which seems to indicate I should add it to Windows PATH, and I used [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to do that. So now "Path" in my environment variables has ";C:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll" appended to the end. Still no worky. Anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong? My 'program' just looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The PATH environment variable needs to include the directory containing cygwin1.dll, not the path to cygwin1.dll itself.  So just make sure that PATH has the string `"C:\cygwin\bin"` in it.

Comment: Haha, I tried C:\cygwin but it didn't occur to me to do C:\cygwin\bin. It works. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to get the window to stay for long enough to see the output. :D

Comment: Run it from the command line - run cmd.exe (or, better yet, just run Cygwin), navigate to the executable's directory, and run the executable from the command line.

Comment: Or put in a Read after you printf.

Comment: Hmm, on my PC neither `C:\cygwin\bin` or `C:\cygwin64\bin` exist... I expected Windows to be equipped with `cygwin` by default and that no installations were necessary.

Answer (score 15):

By the way, I *implore* you not to blindly add a directory containing cygwin1.dll to the system PATH. The path is searched sequentially. If you happen to have older or newer versions of the Cygwin runtime in the path, other programs linked against cygwin1.dll might break horribly (and it's not trivial to figure out what happened unless you know that you're looking for a different DLL version.)

What you should do is copy cygwin1.dll (and other Cygwin DLLs your program might require) into the directory which holds your binary then create an empty (zero byte length) file with the same name as your executable but with `.local` appended, i.e., if your executable is `mytest.exe`, you create a file named `mytest.exe.local` . That will tell the PE loader to *first* look for required DLLs in the same directory that holds your binary, thus avoiding a lot of headache later on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Adam Rosenfield's answer solved it nice. At my Computer the path needs to be `"C:\cygwin64\bin"`

First time I didn't recognized that my version of cygwin is the 64bit... But it's quiet clear that these little difference in the path-variable decides if it will work - or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add: **`;C\cygwin64\bin`** to the **end** of your Windows *system* `PATH` variable.

Also, to compile for use in **CMD** or **PowerShell**, you may need to use:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -static -std=c++11 prog_name.cc -o prog_name.exe
```

<sub>(This invokes the cross-compiler, if installed.)</sub>