# cygwin1.dll missing when compiling c++ with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and when I'm compiling hello world with gcc somehow the compiler doesn't understand about using std namespaces (some of them are missing), but when I compile with g++ yes they work. But when I click on the helloworld.exe it says that cygwin1.dll is missing.

Is there anything can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"gcc" is the C compiler - and namespaces are not a part of the C language. "g++" is the C++ compiler, so it will understand namespaces.

Try the [`no-cygwin`](http://www.delorie.com/howto/cygwin/mno-cygwin-howto.html) option when compiling to produce executables that depend on the mingw runtime instead of the cygwin runtime (which, AFAIR, introduces licencing issues).

Comment: anyway i found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338406/cygwin1-dll-not-found-when-running-a-program-written-in-c-how-can-i-make-windo thanks stupid me not opening the gcc website before posting anything here :|

Answer (score 0):

cygwin1.dll errors could indicate a registry problem, a virus or malware.

Don't download cygwin1.dll. It can be an inappropriate version, or just unsafe.
Try to reinstall cygwin (or try mingw32).