# Is it possible to compile c++ without any lib?

Tags: c++, compilation

Is it possible to compile c++ without any lib?
Because when i was trying to compile my program with Mingw and cygwin  after the .exe file was made i couldn't run it and it said there is a missing library. For cygwin it was "cygwin1.dll".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338406/cygwin1-dll-not-found-when-running-a-program-written-in-c-how-can-i-make-windo

Comment: @Griwes: Hardly. That guy wanted to find the library; this one wants not to use it (but can't).

Comment: @Griwes: Same issue, different questions.

Comment: "Mingw and cygwin after the .exe file was made i couldn't run it and it said there is a missing library." - the problem is the same, just OP tried to solve it the other way around here.

Comment: is this question was about specific compiler implementation or about c++ in general? for example vc++ has no dependancy from cygwin1.dll, but it does not mean that target .exe linked without any lib.

Comment: @Griwes: Same "problem" but the two OPs want to do two completely opposite things.

Comment: I think that main point of OP is to get things working, but in wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binaries that are build with Cygwin always has dependency on `cygwin1.dll`. Hovewer, if you want to avoid this, use linker option `-mno-cygwin`. This way you'll make sure that there will be no dependency on cygwin runtime library that you need to ship with your app.

MinGW has some local dependencies too. In particular, `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`(depends on what unwinding type is used in your toolchain) and `mingwm10.dll`. To get rid of them, use `-static-libgcc` and `-mthreads` options for your linker. Please note that C++ exceptions depends on this option.

Small note, however. Your question - "Is it possible to compile c++ without any lib?" is incorrect, since there are *always* some dependencies on libs (unless you are building binary for barebone hardware w/o OS), for example user32.dll for Windows. Sure, nor Cygwin nor MinGW is suitable for that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just a library; it's the runtime that you need to run applications compiled with Cygwin.

If you're really using MinGW then you can avoid Cygwin entirely with `-mno-cygwin` but even then you're going to need the MinGW runtime and, probably, the C++ Standard Library. However, these can generally be linked *statically* so that you don't need to ship any dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

General answer - no.
The runtime support required by C++ code in general, to enable features like RTTI and exception handling.
So anyway you'll must link executable with libstdc++, either dynamically or statically.